# TF400889 Error while copying from TFS Server through TeamFoundation.Client

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I've been working on a tool which copies source code from TFS. I'm using the followings.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
```

The program works fine for shorter paths. But for long ones (greater than 260) it throws TF400889 error. which is due to long path on client/Application side.

I had faced same issues while copying files. For that I added this in **app.manifest**

```
<windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
    <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
  </windowsSettings>
```

I believe that it would enable application to overcome the 260 character limitation. But it is not working in this case (why?). I don't want change the mapping as it won't accomplish much because there are many folders and files which are longer than 280-300 characters. Also, I cannot use any 3rd party libraries in this project.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Windows limitation, not TFS. According to [this UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2156195-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation), the limitation has been removed from the BCL for the basic file manipulation functionality. You can find more details here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/,

Comment: But isn't that supposed to be resolved by using the longPathAware in app.manifest ?